# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable while loading and testing PyTorch model

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to load and test my final trained PyTorch model but I am getting the following error. What am I doing wrong?

**Original Code:**

```
class_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

model = torch.load('Final_model.pth.tar')

normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.4914, 0.4824, 0.4467],std=[0.2471, 0.2435, 0.2616])
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),normalize])
val_set = datasets.CIFAR10('../data', train=False,download=True,transform=transform)

for i in range(48,64):
    plt.subplot(4,4,i+1-48)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1,wspace=1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow(val_set.data[i])
    out = model(transform(val_set.data[i]).view(1,3,32,32))[0].tolist()
    plt.xlabel(class_names[out.index(max(out))])
```

**Error:**

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-8554fc617196> in <module>()
     18     plt.yticks([])
     19     plt.imshow(val_set.data[i])
---> 20     out = model(transform(val_set.data[i]).view(1,3,32,32))[0].tolist()
     21     plt.xlabel(class_names[out.index(max(out))])
     22 

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: I recommend extracting some of the sub-expressions from line 20 onto their own lines as variables. The line number will help you find the offending snippet.

Comment: How did you save your model?

Comment: It seems what you saved was a dictionary and not the entire model, in which case the error would make sense.

Comment: I see. I used torch.save function to save the model.

Comment: It would have saved the state_dict, you need to recreate the model using the same code as before, but then use `model.load_state_dict(torch.load(Final_model.path.tar'))`

Comment: and your dataloader for val_set is also missing